How to implement a feature that reduces the speed of automated test execution in selenium without using any kind of waits
I guess everyone has faced it Sometimes the text scripting execution are pretty fast enough and we cant see them also because of speed and synchronisation we get quite a few failures which are not actually a failure
I want to implement something where I can control the speed of execution lets say by default at 1x speed and the time take in execution is 10 second when I change the speed of execution to 0.5x it should take 20 seconds

sleep would work  (just implement a sleep between each driver method called)  I think this is not really the correct solution for "we get quite a few failures which are not actually a failure".  You need to take those one at a time.  Be sure to catch exceptions as selenium's exceptions will tell you a lot about the problem(s).
